# Special Characters in Username for SSH not passing to remote device

Tags: ssh, rhel, special-characters

I've been trying to beat my head around this. Bing, Google, and Yahoo don't seem to get my question, hence here I am.

I have a user `D5P$3r` that I need to pass from my Linux Server to my router.

I've tried the following.

```
ssh -c 3des-cbc D5P$3r@Router
ssh -l D5P$3r Router 
ssh -c 3des-cbc -o User=D5P$3r Router
```

No matter what, the end result is:

```
D5Pr@Router's password:
```

I'm not in engineering, so my ideas are ignored hence the reason why this user was even used.

Basically I'm just trying to see how I can get the `$3` to pass through to the Router's username.

The Linux Server is Red Hat Enterprise 7.6.

Comment: Quote the strings that contain special characters, e.g. `ssh -c 3des-cbc 'D5P$3r'@Router` or  `ssh -c 3des-cbc 'D5P$3r@Router'`

Comment: That worked, Why didn't I think of that? lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$3` is the third positional parameter (typically the third argument given to the current shell or shell function).  Since your string `D5P$3r` is unquoted, the shell will expand `$3` to the value of the third positional parameter. If this value is non-existent or empty, the string will be passed to `ssh` as `D5Pr`.

To avoid having the shell expand `$3`, make sure to use single quotes around the string, e.g.,

```
ssh -c 3des-cbc 'D5P$3r@Router'
```

... or escape the `$`,

```
ssh -c 3des-cbc D5P\$3r@Router
```